# How do I get sum of identical rows in a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got a problem with my SQL code, I use multiple joins from different tables and my code looks like this:

```
SELECT Person.navn, Vare.varenavn, Ordre.antal FROM Ordre
JOIN Person
ON Person.Id = Ordre.P_id
JOIN Vare
ON Vare.Id = Ordre.vareid
```

My problem is that it turns out like this

[image]

I want it to remove duplicates and add the numbers together in the "antal" column so it should be: "Tulle - Banan - 9"

Thank you!

**Edit:**

I changed my datatypes from text to nvchar and varchar. I used @lad2025's top answer.

Comment: You should edit the question and include sample data and desired results *as text*.  Links are prone to failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need grouping and `SUM` aggregate function:

```
SELECT Person.navn, Vare.varenavn, SUM(Ordre.antal) AS antal
FROM Ordre
JOIN Person
  ON Person.Id = Ordre.P_id
JOIN Vare
  ON Vare.Id = Ordre.vareid
GROUP BY Person.navn, Vare.varenavn;
```

**EDIT:**

Do not use obsolete types `text/ntext/image`, for now you can use `CAST` but you should consider changing column datatype:

```
SELECT CAST(Person.navn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
       CAST(Vare.varenavn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
       SUM(Ordre.antal) AS antal
FROM Ordre
JOIN Person
  ON Person.Id = Ordre.P_id
JOIN Vare
  ON Vare.Id = Ordre.vareid
GROUP BY CAST(Person.navn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), CAST(Vare.varenavn AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

**[`ntext, text, and image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)**:

> **ntext, text, and image** data types will be removed in a future version
>   of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: It comes up with this error: Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 99
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: Are you trying to select other columns too?

Comment: I just copied what lad2025 posted

Comment: Thank you @lad2025 will mark as done when I can, I will change my types from text to nvchar(max) :)

Comment: Long types (like `ntext`, `text`, `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`) are not appropriate for person names. Usually `NVARCHAR(50)` is fully sufficient. The long types should be used for free text like comments.